# MySQL: Select a fixed value based on UNIQUE only values of another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with values in a column called OrderID. The values aren't all unique and often two or more rows will share the same value. What I'm trying to do, when I make a Select, I want to add a fixed value based only on UNIQUE or DISTINCT values from the OrderID column. I've tried a `SELECT DISTINCT` but of course that just gives me distinct only rows, as I still need to return all of the data. I played around with `UNION` by having one query return all of the results and the other return only DISTINCT results, but I still didn't get the final result I was looking for.

Below is basically what I'm trying to accomplish. It seems like it should be easy, but I'm not sure how to tell my fixed value `SELECT` to only look for distinct values in a specific column. Keep in mind, my full dataset is much greater, I've just paired it down to what I think is necessary.

```
OrderID
  123
  456
  789
  246
  357
  456
  123
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
OrderID || Price
  123        3
  456        3
  789        3
  246        3
  123        
  357        3
  456
  579        3
```

Comment: Do you know about aggregate functions?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I've used `group concat` before. The others I'm not familiar with.